# laplace equation in a rectangle with boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 \quad in \quad  the \quad  rectangle  \quad 0<x<a  \quad 0<y<1$

$u=0  \quad on \quad y=1$

$u=j(y) \quad on \quad x=0 $

$u_y +u=0  \quad on \quad y=0$

$u_x=0  \quad on \quad x=a$

I tried variable separation method. And the result is that this problem is not solved by this method.

Answer (score 3):

Variable separation works... the  Sturm–Liouville problem in $y$-variable has solutions
$$\phi_n(y)=\sin \lambda_n y -\lambda_n \cos \lambda_n y$$
where $\lambda_n>0$ are the roots of the equation  $\tan \lambda=\lambda$.

The solution is obtained in the form $$u(x,y)=\sum_n c_n \sinh [\lambda_n (x-a)]\, \phi_n(y)$$  where the coefficients $c_n$ come from expanding the function $j$ in the basis $(\phi_n)$.